# What am I doing wrong in this INSERT ROW statement (java)

Tags: java, sql, database, object-oriented-database

I am trying to use a statement that will insert a row in a table once the user types a name and ID number into a text field.  However I keep getting an error when trying to run the program and I literally copied the exact format from my Java book for the INSERT statement.  See below:

```
            String insertStudentStatement = "INSERT INTO Students " +
                                      "(StudentId, StudentName) " +
                                      "VALUES ("' + 
                                      studentId + "', " + 
                                      studentName + "')";
```

I know I must have the quotes wrong for the VALUES?? Here is the error I keep getting:

CourseSystem.java:323: error: unclosed character literal
"VALUES ("' +
^
CourseSystem.java:325: error: not a statement
studentName + "')";
^

Comment: Please do **NOT** concatenate values into a SQL string like that. Learn how to properly use a `PreparedStatement` - as an added bonus, your problem then goes away as as well.

Comment: Use parameterized statements.

Comment: Also, you need another double quote `"` after `VALUES ("'` before the `+`

Comment: It's probably worth mentioning _why_ SQL should not be embedded in a string like this.  I.e. it introduces the risk of "SQL Injection".  See https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_injection.asp

Answer (score 3):

```
String insertStudentStatement = "INSERT INTO Students " +
                                  "(StudentId, StudentName) " +
                                  "VALUES ('" + studentId + "', '" + 
                                  studentName + "')";
```

I think this should give the correct syntax assuming StudentId is a text type and not numeric.

Please also consider the other responses suggesting [PreparedStatements](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html) with parameters. This reduces SQL injection risks and manages quotes out of the box.

Comment: THANK YOU! That worked. I will learn how to use prepared statements...I'm a student and just started learning Java and my book must have had a typo for the format.

Answer (score 1):

Just make sure you have your brackets and quotes right. Remember you need single (') quotations around String values for SQL but you don't need any around numbers. So for your values:

```
String insertStudentStatement = "INSERT INTO Students (StudentId, StudentName) "
    + "VALUES ('" + StudentId + "', '" + StudentName + "')";
```

You should consider using PreparedStatements to build your queries instead. Using place holders ("?") and replacing them with the appropriate values by calling setters.

Comment: This is not the good way to use prepared Statements. The idea behind the use of prepared statements is to use "?" placeholders in your SQL and call the setters to pass the values and not building the SQL by concatenation of strings.

Answer (score 0):

Scrambled and missing quotes, try this format for clarity:

```
String insertStudentStatement = "INSERT INTO Students (StudentId, StudentName) VALUES ('"
                              + studentId
                              + "', '"
                              + studentName
                              + "')";
```